# Renaming name attribute in <input> in different tables

Tags: jquery

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pceh73g8/

In my script, I'm going to be loading tables that are going to be the same. The 
following is my example:

```
<table class="table">
<tr><td>First Name</td><td><input name="firstname" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input name="lastname" type="text"></td></tr>
</table>

 <table class="table">
 <tr><td>First Name</td><td><input name="firstname" type="text"></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input name="lastname" type="text"></td></tr>    
</table>
```

I wish to write a script to rename the  names by index. Eventually, the output should be the following:

```
 <table class="table">
<tr><td>First Name</td><td><input name="firstname1" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input name="lastname1" type="text"></td></tr>
</table>


 <table class="table">
 <tr><td>First Name</td><td><input name="firstname2" type="text"></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input name="lastname2" type="text"></td></tr>    
</table>
```

I was trying to use .each() to go through each table, and get the index number of each table (to attach to the back of the input names).

I am unsure on how to select the  within each of the tables. I seemed to be selecting all the :inputs instead. How do we select the "Children" of each table that are  fields and rename them according to the index?

```
 $(".table").each(function(){ 
   //Get current index of the table 
   var i = $(this).index();

    $(":input").each(function(){ 
       var oldname = $(this).attr('name'); 
       $(this).attr('name',oldname+i);
    });

});
```

Comment: for-loop: `for(var i = 1; i < tables.lentgh; i++) name + i`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you are using a non-context specific `$(':input')` selector for each iteration, so all the input elements will just receive the index of the final `<table>` element. Use `$(this)` instead, and DOM transversal methods.

Also, [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) comes with a zero-based index `i`, so you actually don't have to redeclare it within the function :) however, note that since it is **zero**-based (i.e. starts from zero, and not one), you will have to add 1 to it (so you will have `firstname1` instead of `firstname0` for the first occurrence of an input element, for example).

```
$(".table").each(function(i){ 
    $(this).find(":input").each(function(){ 
        var oldname = $(this).attr('name'); 
        $(this).attr('name',oldname+(i+1));
    });    
});
```

See fixed fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/pceh73g8/4/

---

As per [@dsfq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213067/renaming-name-attribute-in-input-in-different-tables#27213121), you can also take advantage of using the `.attr()` method which accepts functions. I still learn something new everyday on here ;)

Answer (score 4):

Find input elements within each table with [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

```
$(".table").each(function () {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $(this).find(":input").attr('name', function (ind, oldname) {
        return oldname + i;
    });
});
```

Also you can use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method as a setter instead of `each` loop.

Also `$(this).find(":input")` is equivalent to `$(":input", this)` if you like it more.

Comment: This is a rather interesting solution! I have totally forgotten that `.attr()` also accepts functions ;) +1

Comment: Yes, many jQuery getter/setter methods allow setter to be a function, which is very convenient.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to add `this` to second each(the second parameter provides the context in which to search the element matched by the first selector):

```
$(".rename").click(function () {
    $(".table").each(function () {
        var i = $(this).index();
        $(":input", this).each(function () { //add this
            var oldname = $(this).attr('name');
            $(this).attr('name', oldname + i);
        });
    });
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j4pdzkm9/)

Answer (score 1):

Just maintain a counter variable and increment it

```
var i = 0;
$('.table').each(function(){
   i++; // increment
   $(this).find('[name=firstname]').attr("name", function(_, n){ return n + i; });
   $(this).find('[name=lastname]').attr("name", function(_, n){ return n + i; });
});
```